# Is the Runtime MCycles on App Engine Dashboard an average or total?

Tags: google-app-engine, dashboard

In the Current Load table there is a list of URIs with Request/Min, number of Requests in the last X hours, and Runtime MCycles for the last hour, and Average Latency.

**I would like to know if the Runtime MCycles is the total for all requests to that URI in the last hour or perhaps an average for each request to the URI.**

*It's confusing because the Request count is provided in xHours where x changes based on what time of the day it is.*

*Also, the numbers in my app make it look a little confusing too because a URI that I think is doing lots of work and many thousands of hits, but others that dont seem to do a lot of work and only it a few hundred times but have a high MCycles*

Answer (score 1):

The Runtime MCycles column indicates the average CPU cycles used *per request*.

If you'd like, you can confirm this for yourself through experimentation.  Also, if you look at the underlying HTML source for the dashboard page, the Runtime MCycles column's title is "Average Runtime CPU Megacycles Per Request."